# Search through string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Say I have a string like this:

> jJKld-xxx-JKl122

Using javascript, how can I get on what's in-between the `-` characters? In others words, all I need to do is put whatever is `xxx` into a variable.

Thanks

Comment: always have a habit of posting `what have you tried`! otherwise it's a good question!

Comment: Do you know for sure that that will be the format? Is it possible that you can have more -s in the string?

Comment: added a working demo in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the string is **always** in that format, this will work:

```
var foo = 'jJKld-xxx-JKl122';
var bar = foo.split('-')[1]; // = xxx
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

just try it with this simple regex

```
var str = 'jJKld-xxx-JKl122';
var xxx = str.replace( /^[^\-]*-|-[^\-]*$/g, '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following regex to get the result

```
var myString = "jJKld-xxx-JKl122";
var myRegexp = /(?:^|\s*)-(.*?)-(?:^|\s*)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

See the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8X8wH/)